# Having trouble with apt-get upgrade and removing KDE Plasma

Tags: apt, kde, dependencies, 15.10, plasma

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 with Gnome DE.  I installed KDE plasma to try it out but `sudo apt-get upgrade` started giving me errors so I ppa-purged the kde ppa and removed kubuntu desktop with the terminal in Gnome.  Now when I run `sudo apt-get upgrade` , I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    kde-telepathy-minimal : Depends: kde-config-telepathy-accounts 
    (>= 15.04.0) but it is not installed.
```

`sudo apt-get install -f` does not resolve the issue.
I tried `sudo apt-get remove kde-telepathy-minimal` to remove the package which gives me this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
kde-telepathy : Depends: kde-telepathy-minimal
```

Attempting to remove 'kde-telepathy' gives me the original error.  I am stuck. Please help me and thank you Ubuntu community!

Comment: You should remove kde-telepathy and kde-telepathy-minimal at once. Do a 'sudo apt-get purge kde-telepathy kde-telepathy-minimal'. Just to make sure that all of the KDE stuff gets removed, run 'sudo apt-get purge $(apt-mark showmanual | grep kde)' afterwards (but only after looking at what APT wants to remove carefully).

Comment: Good idea FuzzyToothpase, that seems like it should work.  I was able to remove the packages with `dpkg -r --force-depends  kde-telepathy` kde- telepathy-minimal before I had the chance to try out your solution.  I belive the dpkg solution has resolved the problem though.  Thank You for the response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dpkg -r --force-depends kde-telepathy kde-telepathy-minimal`
followed by `sudo apt-get purge $(apt-mark showmanual | grep kde)` and finally
`sudo apt-get autoremove` completely removed KDE Plasma