# Supreme error while updating to KDE on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, kde, libreoffice

So here's the problem.
I've deleted LibreOffice, and installed OpenOffice instead. All good there.
Then, I've installed KDE Plasma. Looks like this guy has a thing for LibreOffice and KDE-TELEPATHY.

Now, the problem is, I tried to uninstall KDE and now I can't. Because of 2 errrs:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

  kde-telepathy-minimal : Depends: kde-config-telepathy-accounts (>= 15.04.0) but it is not installed
  libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:5.1.2) but it is not installed
  libreoffice-java-common : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:5.1.2-0ubuntu1) but it is not installed
  libreoffice-style-breeze : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:5.1.2-0ubuntu1) but it is not installed
  libreoffice-style-elementary : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:5.1.2-0ubuntu1) but it is not installed
  libreoffice-style-galaxy : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:5.1.2-0ubuntu1) but it is not installed
  libreoffice-style-oxygen : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:5.1.2-0ubuntu1) but it is not installed
  libreoffice-style-tango : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:5.1.2-0ubuntu1) but it is not installed
```

And `-f` won't solve the issue. Says it doesn't want to uninstall anything or install it. Any clue? I'm quite new with Ubuntu.

Also, tried `autoremove`, `install`, `install-f`, `update`, `upgrade`, `clean`, none of that worked. HELP!

Comment: Please update your question and change your title to your present problem which is removing KDE

Answer (score -1):

> Hi, had the same problem.

Got it fixed with:

https://askubuntu.com/a/716088

dpkg -r --force-depends kde-telepathy kde-telepathy-minimal followed by sudo apt-get purge $(apt-mark showmanual | grep kde) and finally sudo apt-get autoremove completely removed KDE Plasma

Comment: In such cases you had to flag the question as duplicate of the question you have shared its answer's link.